# How to write a simple loop (for element of a matrix) in Tensorflow?

Tags: matlab, tensorflow

This code is in Matlab2018b + Tensorflow 1.2 (tf) + Numpy (np)

```
%A is a matrix of size [4,10], initialize from the same A_ in Matlab as
A = tf.Variable(np.float32(A_)); 
%Input is a input array of size [1, 10] as
Input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[10]);  %during a loop I pass value to it from Matlab
```

Then I want to do the following thing (example Matlab code):

```
tmp = 0;
for j = 1 : 4
    tmp = tmp + sum((A(j,:)-Input).^2);
end
%The code means: for each row of A, for each element, (A - Input)^2, sum it
```

How to write it in Tensorflow ? Best hope a code could run in Tensorflow 1.2, not necessary 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily translate the code with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros(shape=(4,10))
Input = np.ones(shape=(1,10))
for j in range(A.shape[0]):
    tmp = tmp + np.sum( (A[j,:]-Input)**2 )
```

The output is

```
>>tmp 
>> 40
```

It is a bit different `tensorflow` variables, because you work with objects rather than numerics. You need to adjust the `sum`-command: [reduce_sum](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

A = tf.Variable(np.float32( np.zeros(shape=[4,10]) ));
Input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[10]);

tmp = 0
for j in range(A.shape[0]):
    tmp = tmp + tf.math.reduce_sum( (A[j,:]-Input)**2 )
```

Here the output is an object (have a look at the shape!)

```
>> tmp
>> <tf.Tensor 'add_7:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
```

You can also sum everything up directly

```
tf.math.reduce_sum((A-Input)**2)
```

Comment: Thank you, the code works. And could you explain me further, how do I understand reduce_sum, what does its graph look like? Does this tensorflow code gain lots of  performance rather than the same code writes in matlab or numpy ?

Comment: when there are 10000 inputs and the length of input become [144]? (finally I get a result[10000] correspond to the inputs)